# Exporting SQL DB tables to XML using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, xml

I have created a PHP file for exporting SQL data into an XML file. Unfortunately, a minor thing needs to be done that I got stuck with:

```
$jobtype=$xml->createElement("jobtype",htmlentities($row['jobtype']));
$jobposting->appendChild($jobtype);
```

Above code is working perfectly, however in the output XML file, the job types are shown like this:

```
<jobtype>0</jobtype>
<jobtype>1</jobtype>
<jobtype>2</jobtype>
```

(they are showing 0-1-2 values in the DB as well - when they are displayed in the website, the component displays the predefined jobtype for each value, see below).

I want to have them exported in the XML file like below:

```
0: Full-time
1: Part-time
2: Internship
```

Does anyone know how to put "if-elseif" tags into the PHP code to get it converted? Thanks in advance! :]

Comment: It depends on what you are trying to achieve. Are you creating an API? if so REST is way easier than XML. Are you trying to actually export your data so that you can import it later? checkout the --xml option to the mysql client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a switch case statement for this:

```
<?php

switch ($row['jobtype']) {
    case 0:
        $type = '0: Full-time';
        break;
    case 1:
        $type = '1: Part-time'; 
        break;
    case 2:
        $type = '2: Internship'; 
        break;
    default:
        break;
}

$jobtype=$xml->createElement("jobtype",htmlentities($type));
$jobposting->appendChild($jobtype);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a little function :

```
function transcript($nb){
  if($nb == 0){
    $ret = "Full-time";
  }else if($nb == 1){
    $ret = "Part-time";
  }else if($nb == 2){
    $ret = "Internship";
  }
  return $ret;
}
```

Edit : Using switch is a another good way

Comment: Thanks for the fast response! ;]